# jQuery not refreshing the select element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I cannot seem to get the following function to work properly when clicking a button to fetch the data from my MVC4/WebAPI application. The problem is that when I click the button that calls this function, it works on the first call, it fetched the data and the controls get populated with the appropriate data.

But when I click the button a second time, the select element (#lstItems) goes back to the first option instead of the selected item in the returned record. I thought that by sprinkling selectmenu('refresh') would do the trick but to no avail.

```
function getPOById() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: webroot + "api/items?POId=" + $("#txtPOId").val(),
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#txtSupplierName").val(data.SupplierName);
        $("#txtQuantity").val(data.Quantity);
        $("#txtUnitPrice").val(data.UnitPrice);
        $('#lstItems option').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            $("#lstItems").selectmenu("refresh");
            if ($(this).attr('value') == data.ItemId) {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');                    
            }
            $("#lstItems").selectmenu("refresh");
        });            
    }).fail(function (err) {
        alert("Error " + err.status + "Code " + err.statusCode); 
    });
    $("#lstItems").selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

Comment: If `#lstItems` is a `<select>`, you can just do this: `$('#lstItems').val(data.ItemId);`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in the data appends to the previous data.
You will have to 'reset' or clear the contents your select menu as the first part of your done function before populating it again

```
.done(function (data) {
$("#lstItems").html('');

....
```